# Any quick, easy ways to convert ERC-20 tokens?

Tags: erc-20, cpp-ethereum, airdrop

Are there any quick ways to convert my Airdrop ERC-20 tokens from various old ETH wallets to ETH/BTC...?  Looks like I've got a few hundred $ kicking around in old Airdrop tokens.

I've seen a few methods on here that are quite technical and require token specific transactions to transfer each token type to various different exchange accounts.  (a) I'm not confident I could to do that, and (b) I can't seem to find exchanges that support all my tokens.

Here's an example of one of the old wallets I'm trying to clear out:  https://etherscan.io/address/0x51855d982c8e69888a9548dbe35e38a20cebe2ea

This one contains: DATA, ELEC, OMG, XNN, AIC... I have 6 other wallets with a mix of other tokens.

Do any wallets or web-services provide a simple one hit conversion?

Comment: please help i have sent usdt from kucoin to USDC at crypto.com by mistake i am attaching a screen shot just so you can look at it and tell me if any thing can be done the coinbase is doing nothing but ignore the matter[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ckur5.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ckur5.png)

Comment: How long of takes for ERC20 to be converted to.etherum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use Ethersweep, it converts the whole lot in one go.

http://ethersweep.com

It's a new platform... I just tested your wallet ID and your tokens are definitely supported, the quote looks about right.

*(Disclaimer - part of the Ethersweep dev team.  Feel free to AMA)*

Answer (score 1):

**Not all the exchanges will support all of your coins**. Also, as the case was with the crypto-boom, some of your tokens are worth very little or zero, traditionally speaking, they are in the bear market.

The best bet you have and the only option (as far as I'm aware), is to find 'markets'/exchanges where your tokens are being traded. For that, there are good options.

Search your coins on any of these and find the exchanges they are traded on and then go to the corresponding exchange to cash out.

[Coincodex](https://coincodex.com/crypto/omisego/exchanges/) (Will take you to a search I made for OmniseGO but you get the idea)

[Coincap](https://coincap.io/)

[Cryptocompare](https://www.cryptocompare.com/coins/list/USD/1)