# How can I check if the tokens that I have in a certain wallet are valid

Tags: wallets, tokens, erc-20, ico

With the rise of so many ICOs and ERC20 tokens, I decided to join one of them out of curiosity but their token sale had finished and I decided to purchase some from an exchange, but the company behind the token says we don't recommend buying from any exchanges at this moment and your purchases are at your own risk.

This later on raised the question in my head that how can we check the authenticity of a certain wallet address against a, let's say ERC20 token?

I have also heard that Ether wallets are capable of receiving any ERC20 token, if that's true, how does the wallet and/or Ethereum platform keeps track of what represents what?

Comment: You might find this question useful: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/29236/how-do-erc-20-tokens-work

Comment: @lungj It was helpful, thanks! Now let's say I'm searching my wallet address on etherscan.io website and it does not find it. Can we conclude anything based on that?

Comment: Glad it was helpful! Sounds like a new question to me ;) (Also, the full answer wouldn't fit in a comment)

Comment: Fair enough, new question coming soon, stay tuned!